# How to make 2 columns in dropdownlist while parsing XML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, drop-down-menu, xml-parsing

```
remcl3.Wcl3Client client = new remcl3.Wcl3Client();
string rrs = client.getsql("sabatini", "ZXCqwe1920",112, w);            

string xml = @rrs;

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("AC_NO");
XmlNodeList elem = doc.GetElementsByTagName("AC_NAME");

for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
{
    rem_no.DataTextField = doc.GetElementsByTagName("AC_NO").ToString();
    rem_no.Items.Add(elemList[i].InnerXml);
    rem_no.DataValueField = doc.GetElementsByTagName("AC_NAME").ToString();
    rem_no.Items.Add(elem[i].InnerXml);
}
```

I'm trying to parse XML with two fields `ac_no`, `ac_name` using C# ASP.NET and put the data value, data text for the dropdownlist and bind the data value.

I have tried the following code but with no luck:

[image: this is what appears in the browser]

I want to bind the `ac_no` and show the `ac_name`; any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `DataTable`:

**C# Code:**

```
remcl3.Wcl3Client client = new remcl3.Wcl3Client();
string rrs = client.getsql("sabatini", "ZXCqwe1920",112, w);            

string xml = @rrs;

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("AC_NO");
XmlNodeList elem = doc.GetElementsByTagName("AC_NAME");

DataTable table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.Add("AC_NO");
table.Columns.Add("AC_NAME");

for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();

    var value = elemList[i].InnerXml;
    var text = elem[i].InnerXml;

    row["AC_NO"] = value;
    row["AC_NAME"] = text;

    table.Rows.Add(row);
}

// Configure your Dropdownlist
rem_no.DataSource = table;
rem_no.ValueMember = "AC_NO";
rem_no.DisplayMember = "AC_NAME";
rem_no.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Or use a `ListItem`:

**C# Code:**

```
remcl3.Wcl3Client client = new remcl3.Wcl3Client();
string rrs = client.getsql("sabatini", "ZXCqwe1920",112, w);            

string xml = @rrs;

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("AC_NO");
XmlNodeList elem = doc.GetElementsByTagName("AC_NAME");

for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++) 
{
    var value = elemList[i].InnerXml;
    var text = elem[i].InnerXml;

    rem_no.Items.Add(new ListItem(text, value));
}
```